# Increment/alter integer column of several records at once in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have records who have a priority, now I want to give the user the ability to select some records and add +200 priority to all selected records.
One way to do this is to
1) get the record (read the priority)
2) add the relative change and save it again

Is there a way to do this in less/one query?

I am using Rails 3 with PostgreSQL 9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a SQL query like this:

```
update table
    set priority = priority + 200
    where RecordId in (<list provided by user>);
```

Comment: oh, nice! 
Do you by any chance also know how to craft this query with rails / what should i search for?

Comment: @YoLudke . . . No I don't.  I would suggest that you ask another question and tag it with "rails" or the appropriate keyword.

Comment: easy, just tried it: `list.update_all("priority = priority + 200")`